# Xcode compiler copies unwanted files

Tags: ios, xcode

When I compile my iPhone application, i don't know why, while compiling Xcode is copying on my iPad many fines that are not relevant for the project like photographs, files, mp3, and other stuff in my documents and downloads folder. I checked in my project files and folders, and there is no copy of the unwanted folders and files. there was a link to my downloads folder, but I deleted it. Anybody know why?? >For this reason my app under usages is said to be 2.5 gb big!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your target Build Phases and look for the Copy Bundle Resources phase.

There, you will find a list with all the files that are copied over to your bundle. Just remove those you do not want to be copied.

[image]
<sub>(source: [ajaxapp.com](http://www.ajaxapp.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/Project-build-phases-to-add-frameworks.jpg))</sub>

Comment: I went their and there are listed the right files, I can't see any of the unwanted files. How can it be??

Comment: then, clean up your build; possibly this was a leftover from some previous wrong state of your project build phases.

Comment: I found the command but it says: This will delete all of the products and intermediate files in the build folder. Is it safe, what does it delete?

Comment: yes, it is safe, because those files are what the compiler and linker make. in any case, you should keep two or three  backup copies of your source files, source control, etc., in case you did not... :-)